# Cannot find the X.509 certificate in WCF service hosted in Azure

Tags: wcf, authentication, azure, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to make a certificate based authentication platform for my WCF service, and I've followed all the tutorials and made my certificate and installed it in IIS and everything works great running locally, but as soon as I publish it to Azure I get the exception

```
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'CN=tempCert'.
```

**I've uploaded the .pvk to azure**

[image]

**I've put it in my settings**

[image]

**And I made sure to add it to my app settings for the website**

[image]

However it still does not work once I publish it. This is my configuration in my `Web.Config` file for the service model

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="clientSecurity">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
      name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="uConnect.Web.IUConnectService" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=tempCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And as I mentioned it works perfectly when I run it locally, it only throws an exception once I publish it to azure. Any help would be welcome since I've been trying to fix this for some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the certificate store, in Azure WebApps - these get loaded in currentUser. Add `storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My"` to the serviceCertificate element.